# If date is older then today's date it will not show on page

Tags: php, mysql, date

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);

$query = "SELECT code , value , type ,expirationdate, notes, startdate  FROM tblpromotions";
echo "<b> <center></center> </b> <br> <br>";
 if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $field1name = $row["code"];
    $field2name = $row["value"];
    $field3name = $row["type"];
    $field4name = $row["expirationdate"];
    $field5name = $row["notes"];
    $field6name = $row["startdate"];
```

I can not Figure out how to Make it where older date will not show on the page 
exp

expirationdate = 12/1/2019 and Then today date is 12/8/2019
That Table will not be showen on the page

if posts are expired i dont want to show them ?

Comment: I dont understand you question... Can you please specify it?

Comment: if posts are expired i dont want to show them?

Comment: You should not be storing dates as text. In doing that, it makes it harder to query and having to resort to use an additional function via PHP. MySQL has built-in functions for this and by altering your column type to be `DATE` and starting over. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: dates are store as date There Type date

Answer (score 1):

So you can just ask if expiration date is lower than today:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $exp_date = $row["expirationdate"];
    $today = date("Y-m-d");

    if (date("Y-m-d", strtotime($exp_date)) < $today) {
        $field1name = $row["code"];
        $field2name = $row["value"];
        $field3name = $row["type"];
        $field4name = $row["expirationdate"];
        $field5name = $row["notes"];
        $field6name = $row["startdate"];
    }
}
```

You can change `$today` value to another date by `$today = "2019-8-12"`

**NOTE: This works just with DATE stored in format YYYY-mm-dd**

Comment: How you store dates in database? What structure it have?

Comment: expirationdate is store as dates  and formate 2019-12-08

Comment: Please note this only work if you store the date with `YYYY-MM-DD` format, other format might not work as expected

Comment: Ya there store just like this 2019-12-08

Comment: I edit my post because I think I find mistake in my code try it now

Comment: Fix it  Ty so much

Comment: had to add .$field6name.

Comment: And press confirmation please to tell other people that its already solved thanks